# Cant add new contact using expo-contacts in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, contacts

I am doing a contacts app using expo-contacts, I can see contacts but the problem comes when I need to add one.

This is the code I am using, the thing is that in some phones works and in other doesn't. Just to let you know, the permissions to write and read are already attached in app.json.

```
<Button
                title="Guardar"
                onPress={async () => {
                  const contact = {
                    [Contacts.Fields.FirstName]: "Test",
                    [Contacts.Fields.LastName]: "McTest",
                    [Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]: [
                      {
                        number: "(123) 456-7890",
                        isPrimary: true,
                        digits: "1234567890",
                        countryCode: "PA",
                        id: "1",
                        label: "main",
                      },
                    ],
                    [Contacts.Fields.Emails]: [
                      {
                        email: "test@gmail.com",
                        isPrimary: true,
                        id: "2",
                        label: "main",
                      },
                    ],
                  };

                  await Contacts.addContactAsync(contact)
                    .then((contactId) => {
                      alert("Se creó exitosamente");
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      alert(err);
                      console.log(err);
                    });
                }}
```

The error I am getting is this: Error: insert into content://com.android.contacts/data returned no result.

To finish its important to say that I am using apk already built and not doing in debugging mode in expo.

I will appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: it was how i organiced data structure to push contact details.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Contacts.Fields.PhoneNumbers]: [
                  {
                    number: "(123) 456-7890",
                    isPrimary: true,
                    digits: "1234567890",
                    countryCode: "PA",
                    id: "1",
                    label: "main",
                  },
                ]
```

Changing label from 'main' to 'mobile' worked for me.